# To process a folder with xlsx files with openpyxl module

Tags: openpyxl, xlsx

I have folder ('rogaikopyta') with 1 000 files in xlsx format. I need to extract the data form each of these files (B2 and D2 cells) and print them in ordered consequence in one xlsx file. The original code is:

import openpyxl

import os

import pathlib

from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

path = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/DjangoWebProject1/DjangoWebProject1/app/rogaikopyta'

for file in os.listdir(path):

```
wb=load_workbook(os.path.join(path,file), read_only=True)

ws=wb.active

wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)

ws2 = wb2.create_sheet()

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=4, min_row=2, max_row=2, values_only=True):

    ws2.append([row[0], row[-1]])
```

wb2.save("output.xlsx")

It gives a loooot of errors, I suppose, concerning each of the xlsx files!

Like this:

Exception ignored in:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_write_only.py", line 74, in _write_rows

```
pass
```

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in **exit**

```
next(self.gen)
```

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 50, in element

```
self._write_element(el)
```

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 50, in element

```
self._write_element(el)
```

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 78, in _write_element

```
self._file.write(xml)
```

ValueError: write to closed file

And it bothers me a lot! What is goin on with this code?

Comment: Have you done the openpyxl tutorial?

Comment: Yes, but this is about single file or several sheets in one xlsx. I need to operate with a lot of files xlsx

Comment: And you want just B2 and D2 from one sheet in every file?

Comment: Yes, there is only one sheet in each of the 1000 xlsx files... I know there is a problem with command wb=load_workbook()(the argument is needed), but I dunno how to refer to 1000 files!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up on the `os` module and the `pathlib` module, as well as checking that your code is suitable for the more recent versions of openpyxl.

`os.listdir(path)` returns a list of files in a folder so the following should see you on your way

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
target_wb = Workbook()
target_ws = wb.active

for file in os.listdir(path):
    wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, file), read_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=4, min_row=2, max_row=2, values_only=True):
         target_ws.append([row[0], row[-1])
target_wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, now there is another problem, can you please suggest the new code of yours would work or no?(above)